# Find index of max element in numpy array excluding few indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say:

```
p = array([4, 0, 8, 2, 7])
```

Want to find the index of max value, except few indexes, say:

```
excptIndx = [2, 3]
```

Ans: 4, as 7 will be max.

if `excptIndx = [1, 3]`, Ans: 2, as 8 will be max.

Comment: Don't want to mark as duplicate but this is relevant: [How to select inverse of indexes of a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330959/how-to-select-inverse-of-indexes-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = np.array([4,0,8,2,7])   # given
exceptions = [2,3]   # given

idx = list( range(0,len(p)) )   # simple array of index
a1 = np.delete(idx, exceptions)   # remove exceptions from idx (i.e., index)
a2 = np.argmax(np.delete(p, exceptions))   # get index of the max value after removing exceptions from actual p array

a1[a2]   # as a1 and a2 are in sync, this will give the original index (as asked) of the max value
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score 6):

In numpy, you can mask all values at `excptIndx` and run `argmax` to obtain index of max element:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([4, 0, 8, 2, 7])
excptIndx = [2, 3]

m = np.zeros(p.size, dtype=bool)
m[excptIndx] = True
a = np.ma.array(p, mask=m)
print(np.argmax(a))
# 4
```

Comment: I need the index, not max value.

Comment: This gives the index.

Answer (score 2):

The setup:

```
In [153]: p = np.array([4,0,8,2,7])                                                              
In [154]: exceptions = [2,3]
```

Original indexes in `p`:

```
In [155]: idx = np.arange(p.shape[0])
```

`delete` exceptions from both:

```
In [156]: np.delete(p,exceptions)                                                                
Out[156]: array([4, 0, 7])
In [157]: np.delete(idx,exceptions)                                                              
Out[157]: array([0, 1, 4])
```

Find the argmax in the deleted array:

```
In [158]: np.argmax(np.delete(p,exceptions))                                                     
Out[158]: 2
```

Use that to find the max value (could just as well use `np.max(_156)`

```
In [159]: _156[_158]                                                                             
Out[159]: 7
```

Use the same index to find the index in the original `p`

```
In [160]: _157[_158]                                                                             
Out[160]: 4
In [161]: p[_160]    # another way to get the max value                                                                            
Out[161]: 7
```

For this small example, the `pure` Python alternatives might well be faster.  They often are in small cases.  We need test cases with a 1000 or more values to really see the advantages of `numpy`.

Another method

Set the exceptions to a small enough value, and take the `argmax`:

```
In [162]: p1 = p.copy(); p1[exceptions] = -1000                                                  
In [163]: np.argmax(p1)                                                                          
Out[163]: 4
```

Here the `small enough` is easy to pick; more generally it may require some thought.

Or taking advantage of the `np.nan...` functions:

```
In [164]: p1 = p.astype(float); p1[exceptions]=np.nan                                            
In [165]: np.nanargmax(p1) 
Out[165]: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is

```
mask = np.isin(np.arange(len(p)), excptIndx)
subset_idx = np.argmax(p[mask])
parent_idx = np.arange(len(p))[mask][subset_idx]
```

See http://seanlaw.github.io/2015/09/10/numpy-argmin-with-a-condition/

Comment: Well he can just declare `excptIndx = {2, 3}`