# subtract two np.ndarray with different shapes

Tags: python, numpy

ndarray of different shapes and the bigger one has a shape of (22470,2) and it looks like this

```
df1

array([[-0.39911392,  0.46759156],
       [ 0.28343494,  0.88479157],
       [-0.0114085 , -1.23768313],
       ...,
       [-0.35930586,  0.54784439],
       [-0.37994004,  0.51332771],
       [-0.36309593,  0.49318486]])
```

and the small one which represents the outliers of df1 array and its shape is (675,2) and it looks like this

```
df2
array([[-0.04450032,  0.31053589],
       [-0.4320086 ,  0.14815988],
       [-0.07948631, -1.32638555],
       ...,
       [-0.32619787,  0.34910699],
       [-0.50870225, -0.230849  ],
       [-0.43532727,  0.49763502]])
```

so tried to subtract both of them to have a new array that contains everything in df1 except df2 but it gives me this error

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (22470,2) (675,2)

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32832923/6692898

Comment: what is your expected output? I don't understand how your substraction should work

Comment: @RichieV for example if df1=[ [1,2],[2,2],[3,6]] and df2=[2,2] if I subtract both of them or I don't know if substraction is the right term I would like the result be like this dfnew=[1,2],[3,6]]

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/6692898) find `LEFT-Excluding` and you should be set

Comment: What function or operator were you using?  `df1-df2` or something else?

Comment: What's the criteria for keeping or removing elements?  I assume you want some how to match whole rows (2 numbers)? Keep in mind that floats rarely match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

"Subtracting" two arrays does not perform set operations on the arrays, it simply subtracts the values of one from the values of the other (i.e. 4 - 3 => 1).

What you want to do is basically a set operation. There is no simple straightforward way to do what you want, how you have presented it (but that doesn't mean it can't be done). Comparing floating-point numbers for exact equality is a bad idea, instead you will find it much more useful to collect an array of indices of the outliers rather than their values. Then you can index your array like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330959/how-to-select-inverse-of-indexes-of-a-numpy-array).

So this would then be something like

```py
df1 = array([[1.234, 2.345], [3.3452, 2.456], [5.234, 7.453]])

# This is an array of indices, not float values.
df2 = array([1])

keep = np.ones(len(df1), dtype=bool)
keep[df2] = 0
newdf = df1[keep]

# newdf: [[1.234, 2.345], [5.234, 7.453]]
```

Comment: sorry subtraction was rong term to use I don't want to subtract both array I won't a new array that contains everything except the df2 array for example if df1=array([ [1,2],[2,2],[3,6]]) and df2=array([2,2])
the newdf would be new=array([1,2],[3,6])

Comment: Yes I understand that, and that is what I have answered. I will update the answer to be clearer